# How can i get rid of the following highlighted output?

Tags: java

Here is my code

```
while(true)
                {
                // Taking input from the user 
                System.out.print(myBoard.getCurrentPlayer()+" player: ");
                System.out.print("Enter row and column numbers:");
                int row = cin.nextInt()-1;
                int col = cin.nextInt()-1;
                // Checking if input is valid or not
                if(myBoard.setRowCol(row,col))
                break;
                
                               
                else
                System.out.println("Incorrect cell. Try again!");
                System.out.print("Enter row and column numbers:");
                               
                                
                }
```

This then outputs

```
x player: Enter row and column numbers:Incorrect cell. Try again!
Enter row and column numbers:***x player: Enter row and column numbers:***Current Board
```

I want to get rid of the part that I italicized and made bold. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what exactly do you want to get rid of ? Get rid of all code if not fit properly `then` write the good one `else` keep it and run it `while(true)` loop end

Comment: `java != javascript`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood what you wanted, I think that your issue is with the text being printed one extra time.

To fix that, simply take the first two lines out of the loop. To do so, change your code to the following:

```
System.out.print(myBoard.getCurrentPlayer()+" player: ");
System.out.print("Enter row and column numbers:");

while(true) {
   // Taking input from the user 
   int row = cin.nextInt()-1;
   int col = cin.nextInt()-1;

   // Checking if input is valid or not
   if(myBoard.setRowCol(row,col))
      break;
                             
   else System.out.println("Incorrect cell. Try again!");

   System.out.print("Enter row and column numbers:");                         
   }
```

The code block above will print out "Enter row and column numbers:" whether the input was valid or not. However, if you want to print it out only when the input is not valid, then use the following:

```
else {
   System.out.println("Incorrect cell. Try again!");
   System.out.println("Enter row and column numbers:");
}
```

Hope this helps you out.
Also a small advice; try to review your code for such simple issues in the future, you will eventually find where the issue is and most (if not all) of the times solve it, always search and test, and only post when you really need to.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was for my first programming class, still learning